# Rename a character in various filenames inside a subfolder of a folder

Tags: command-line, rename

I am a noob, I have accomplished various things on the cli, however I haven't been able to rename some files
Let me explain with an example.

I have this:

```
folder/
    subfolder/
        fileto_rename.txt
folder2/
    subfolder2/
        fileto_rename2.txt
```

I want to rename to this:

```
folder/
    subfolder/
        filetorename.txt
folder2/
    subfolder2/
        filetorename2.txt
```

I just cant for the life of me understand the instructions on how to do it with find or rename, mv says I need to provide a destination... I hope someone could help me out.
Sorry for my bad English

Comment: please read https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as:

```
rename -n 's/_//' folder/subfolder/*
```

Remove `-n` when satisfied with output to do the actual renaming.

`'s/_//'` will delete all underscore characters in file names.

`folder/subfolder/*` is the path to your files and `*` works on all files in that path.